# How to generate FactoryGirl association with model having multiple associations on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am going through Michael Hartl's tutorial, but with RSpec instead of minitest testing to learn RSpec. I came to the [last chapter](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users) when he created Relationships testing.

Models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
...

class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
end
```

Here is his minitest version (works):

```
class RelationshipTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @relationship = Relationship.new(follower_id: users(:michael).id,
                                     followed_id: users(:archer).id)
  end
...
```

I am trying to recreate this with RSpec + FactoryGirl, but I cannot get Relationship association right.

Here is my current model test:

```
//spec/models/relationship_spec.rb
let(:relationship) {FactoryGirl.create(:relationship)}

  it "should be valid" do
    expect(relationship).to be_valid
  end
```

First I tried to hardcode my Relationship factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :relationship do
    follower_id 1
    followed_id 2
  end
end
// error  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Follower must exist, Followed must exist
```

Then I tried adding `user` (I have another factory for `:user`)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :relationship do
    user
  end
end
// NoMethodError: undefined method `user=' for #<Relationship:0x007fa8b9194a10>
```

Right now hard-coding it `let(:relationship) {Relationship.new(follower_id: 1, followed_id: 2)}` works, but it does not look right. What do I have to do to generate `relationship` factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your hardcoded `follower_id` and `followed_id` values raise an error because those users still don't exist.

For relationships in factory girl you can just write it like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :relationship do
    follower
    followed
  end
end
```

Whenever you call `create(:relationship)` FactoryGirl will create user instances for this new relationship.